# Angular - How to Unit Test a Subscription on a Service?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, rxjs

I've been trying to find a way to test a subscription that is on a mocked service within Angular using Jest. But I can't find a way to mock the Observable and test the assignment of the `isMobile` property.

When I try to spyOn and then mock the service to return a value, it is never updated. And I would like to be able to test the code with different responses from the service.

Code below.

Component

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BREAKPOINT, BreakpointService } from '../../services';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'auxiliary-bar',
  templateUrl: './auxiliary-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auxiliary-bar.component.scss'],
})
export class AuxiliaryBarComponent implements OnInit { 
  public isMobile = false;
 
  constructor(private breakpointService: BreakpointService) {}
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.breakpointService.onBreakpoint$.subscribe(
      (breakpoint) => (this.isMobile = breakpoint <= BREAKPOINT.SM),
    );
  }
}
```

Breakpoint Service

```js
import { Injectable, NgZone, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

export enum BREAKPOINT {
  XS,
  SM,
  MD,
  LG,
  XL,
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BreakpointService implements OnDestroy {
  private breakpointSubject: Subject<BREAKPOINT> = new Subject();
  private observer!: ResizeObserver;
  private sizes = [
    {
      id: BREAKPOINT.SM,
      width: 0,
    },
    {
      id: BREAKPOINT.SM,
      width: 320,
    },
    {
      id: BREAKPOINT.MD,
      width: 768,
    },
    {
      id: BREAKPOINT.LG,
      width: 1024,
    },
    {
      id: BREAKPOINT.XL,
      width: 1200,
    },
  ];

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    this.observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        const matchedSize = this.sizes
          .slice(1)
          .reverse()
          .find(
            (size) => window.matchMedia(`(min-width: ${size.width}px)`).matches,
          );
        this.breakpointSubject.next(
          matchedSize ? matchedSize.id : BREAKPOINT.XS,
        );
      });
    });
    this.observer.observe(document.body);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.observer.unobserve(document.body);
  }

  public get onBreakpoint$(): Observable<BREAKPOINT> {
    return this.breakpointSubject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  }
}
```

Attempted Test Suite

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockProvider } from 'ng-mocks';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { BreakpointService } from '../../services';
import { AuxiliaryBarComponent } from './auxiliary-bar.component';

describe('AuxiliaryBarComponent', () => {
  let component: AuxiliaryBarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuxiliaryBarComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AuxiliaryBarComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        MockProvider(BreakpointService, {
          onBreakpoint$: new Observable(),
        }),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuxiliaryBarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should', () => {
    const breakpointService = TestBed.inject(BreakpointService);
    const spy = jest
      .spyOn(breakpointService, 'onBreakpoint$', 'get')
      .mockReturnValue(of(3));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(breakpointService.onBreakpoint$.subscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
)};
```

Comment: Maybe this example is what you searching for: https://dev.to/lysofdev/an-angular-testing-cheatsheet-5hj2#services

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's too late because the component is already instantiated and therefore ngInit is already called by the time your `it` starts. If I'm right, then a fix might be as easy as inserting `component.ngOnInit()` before your last `fixture.detectChanges()` to re-trigger it.

*As an aside,* your component shouldn't subscribe if you can help it. Instead, if it works for your needs then I would change the component's ngOnInit to

```js
public isMobile$: Observable<boolean>;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isMobile$ = this.breakpointService.onBreakpoint$.pipe(
    map(breakpoint => breakpoint <= BREAKPOINT.SM)
  );
}
```

and then in your template, wherever you used to have `isMobile`, use `(isMobile$ | async)` instead.

But if you must subscribe within a service or component (or maybe also do this for safety and good programming practice), your service should have an ngOnDestroy that calls `this.breakpointSubject?complete();`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think this is a good solution, but what if I want to use the value of isMobile in multiple places in my template? Also I pulled the resize observables out of the component and into a service so that many components can use the same observable, so I would not want to complete the observable onDestroy

Comment: If you want to use an observable in more than one place simultaneously, in this case I'd recommend changing `isMobile$` to a property set in the ngOnInit method, piping a `shareReplay(1)` operator to the end of it. That way you're always sharing the same observable, and only computing the mapping at most once regardless of how many subscriptions, And the benefit of using shareReplay instead of share is that if you have a part of your component that suddenly starts using it (e.g. In an element that is conditionally revealed) it will get the most recent value instead of only future values.